# jQuery Correct ternary operator for multiple conditions inside options of plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, ternary-operator, fullpage.js

I am using the [fullpage](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/) plugin by Alvarotrigo. Its `scrollOverflow` option allows to disable or enable the scroll inside a section. I am trying to enable it and disable it that scrollOverflow option according to these conditions:

- set it to `false` if the window is less that 768 pixels
- set it to `true` if the window is larger than 768 pixel
- set it to `false` after window was resized and the window is less that 768 pixels
- set it to `true` again after was resized and the the window is larger than 768 pixel

Right now I'm only able to enable or disable for the current loaded window, but cannot find the right synthax to do it after window is resized.

```
// var winWidth = $(window).width();

scrollOverflow: (winWidth > 768) ? true : false,
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this ? Im so eager to learn.

I have tryed to use a function and variable which I could use inside the ternary operator but I got lost, and I think I may be complicating things that way?

```
function wasResizedBelow768() {

 var resizedBelow768 = false;

 if (winWidth > 768) {

     $(window).resize(function() {

         if (winWidth < 768) {

             resizedBelow768 = true;

         }
     })
   }

 }
```

Comment: There is no need to write `? true : false`; you already have a boolean.

Comment: why do you need to enable or disable it? Why not change the content of the section or slide and remove or hide what you want to hide overflowing it? That way fullpage.js won't generate the scrollbar in the first place.